# Suggested Configuration of Sputtering System?

Tags: fabrication, semiconductor-process-technology

hopefully this is in the right section, a lot of electrical engineers work in semiconductors. I have an old hummer II desktop sputter coater I am trying to make use of. The documentation of something this old is pretty scant. I have a manual, but the photos are of very little help.

I am trying to work out the configuration of the electrodes, and where I may be able to mount a sputter target? The high power lines go to either center pillar, while the outer ring stays grounded. I presume then only the top or bottom half is made use of at a time, such that in etch mode the bottom pillar acts as the cathode while the ring acts as the anode; then in sputter mode the top half pillar acts as the cathode while the ring acts as the anode? Or is it more likely to have a conventional dual plate setup between the two center electrodes?

Since this is a desktop sputter coater, I should be able to load a target on the top electrode to sputter with Argon. Kurt J. Lesker claims it uses a 2" target, but it is not obvious how it would be mounted? I can make a custom jig for it, but I want to ensure I am not missing something. The top half pillar is 2" in diameter and as stated has high voltage connected to it and it is electrically isolated from the outer ring which is held at ground (see pics). That pillar in the center can be unscrewed but appears to be made of brass, where it is non-magnetic and would not hold a target with a backing plate. It does seem that that top brass plate is separate from the sidewalls (see pic) though I believe that is from how it is manufactured and not where a target would fit.

If I can better figure out how it was supposed to be configured to hold a target I can engineer a custom holder. Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: what's the target? Configs can be rather different for magnetic vs non-magnetic or conducting vs insulating targets.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://laboratoryresource.com.au/?navaction=getitem&id=257) (or [this](https://microwiki.org/media/anatech/technics_hummer_jr_i-v_operation_maintenance.pdf)) help?

> Most targets are held by a cover or are crimped around the edge ‐ if
> yours is not that type it must be glued. The 'glue' used must be
> electrically conducting.
>
> For 'professional' mounting use a few slivers of indium wire on the
> support plate, cover with the target and then either place in an oven
> with a flat weight on top of the target, or use a smoothing iron to
> heat the gold and hence melt the indium. Placing something like a
> piece of lens tissue onto the target would protect it. A temperature a
> little higher than melting point of indium is required (m.p. 156.6°C)
> for a short time. Alternatively use a bit of silver conducting paint,
> preferably a few small drops of paste at the bottom of the jar. You
> could also make a paste using our silver powder and a little
> commercial epoxy glue ‐ the method can be found under Silver powder
> C920 on page C8. Only spot gluing is required, but keep a weight on
> the target while drying/ curing.